# Firefox Gecko SDK : NPP_GetValue not getting called

Tags: firefox, gecko, npapi, firefox3.6

I have tried out the `NPRuntime` sample provided with the Gecko SDK 1.9.1 with the help of [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Compiling_The_npruntime_Sample_Plugin_in_Visual_Studio).

It works perfectly fine with Firefox 3.6.

Following the above steps I created a new scripting plugin (`npmyplugin.dll`). I am currently placing `npmyplugin.dll` in a folder other than `Firefox/plugins`. I am registering the associated mime-type and plugin path in the registry. The plugin gets loaded properly. But now the browser is not calling `NPP_GetValue`.

I was suspecting that it must be because I am placing the plugin in a directory other than `Firefox/plugins`. Hence I did the same with `npruntime.dll` (the sample which comes with Gecko sdk). Suprisingly `npruntime.dll` scripting was working. Please guide me whether I missing anything important while creating the new plugin.

Comment: Try mozilla.dev.tech.plugins <http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.plugins/topics?pli=1> if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Have you checked wether `NP_Initialize()` etc. are getting called?

Comment: I am using firefox version 26.0 then this Gecko SDK will work?

Answer (score 3):

NPP_GetValue doesn't get called to get the NPObject until the first time you access it with javascript in many cases.  When you do a getElementById, it will make the call.

Likely other calls to GetValue are being made, but you aren't seeing them because you aren't handling them. However, that's still not guaranteed.

Comment: As I think on it, I think I have also seen this issue happen when using the <embed> tag on some browsers.  Not sure why.  Just be safe and use <object>; dunno why, but it consistently works better than <embed>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying so late. I somehow solved the problem. I was embedding the plugin using  tag

then i wrote a small javascript code

var MyWorkingPlugin = document.getElementById('MyPlugin');

It seems that after executing the above javascript NPP_GetValue was called. Currently I have no convincing reason why it happened but it worked and I am happy for the moment. If anyone can explain the above behaviour please let us know.